# Backbone base64 encoding

Tags: backbone.js

I don't get how to make Backbone.sync suitable for my case.
That's why I still use this usual Ajax-Request for my project:

```
$.ajax({
    url: request,
    status: status,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (req) { req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth) },
    success: function (data, status) {
           //update the model
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

I need to add a base64 encoded authorization to the request header and update a model. The data I get from the server contain more information than my model needs. That's why I can't refer the model directly to an url like this:

```
var MyApp.myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: '/someResourceUrl'
});
MyApp.myModel.fetch();
```

I need to do sth. like:

```
var MyApp.myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     url: 'anyurl',
     sync: myOwnSpecificSync,
});
//Define the sync function:
myOwnSpecificSync = function(method, model, options) { 
//add header 
//return only specific parameters of the success data
};
//let the model fetch the data from the server
MyApp.myModel.fetch();
```

But I have no idea how to implement the functions .. or if it's correct at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var AuthSync = function(method, model, options) {
  options.beforeSend = function () {
    console.log('add auth header here');
  };
  return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
};

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url : 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/',
  sync : AuthSync
});

new Model().fetch();
```

Comment: I have tried it before post and it works :) Sorry for the lack of explaining I think the code is clear

Comment: If I set the beforeSend method to what I did inside my ajax-request it doesn't work ... function (req) { req.setRequestHeader(...); Do I have to use sth. else but setRequestHeader() ?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. `options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'base64')
  };`